# ListPlot draws nothing

Tags: plotting, bugs, tooltip

Consider the following simplified example:

```
data1 = {{{1, 1}, {8000, 1}}, {{1, 0}, {8000, 0}}};
data2 = {{{1, 1}, {10, 1}, {8000, 1}}, {{1, 0}, {8000, 0}}};
labels = {"L1", "L2"};
Row[ListLinePlot[MapThread[Tooltip, {#, labels}], 
    PlotRange -> All] & /@ {data1, data2}, 
 BaseStyle -> ImageSizeMultipliers -> 1]
```

> [image: output]

In the case of `data1` `ListLinePlot` draws nothing! Addition of one point in the first dataset of `data1` makes it working (`data2`).

Note that without `Tooltip` it works:

```
ListLinePlot[data1, PlotRange -> All]
```

> [image: output]

Why `ListLinePlot` fails to draw the lines of `data1` in the presence of the `Tooltip` wrapper? Is it a bug? Is there a workaround?

Comment: i think this is  related to the issue reported in this q/a: [ListPlot does not plot Labeled data under some conditions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/173744/125)

Comment: it seems that the issue arises more generally when individual datasets each contain two elements. For example, for `d1={{{1, 1}, {8000, 1}},{{1, .5}, {8000, .5}}, {{1, 0}, {8000, 0}}}
d2={{{1, 1},{2,1}, {8000, 1}},{{1, .5}, {8000, .5}}, {{1, 0}, {8000, 0}}}` we get the same issue.

Comment: same issue with `Style`: that is, `ListLinePlot[MapThread[Style, {#, {Red,Green}}], PlotRange -> All]& /@ {data1,data2}`

Comment: I vote for [tag:bugs].  You'd think symmetric cases (2x2) and extreme cases (2 points determine a line) would be in a test suite. (Have you reported it?) There is the ambiguity of a 2x2 array: is it two 1D datasets or one 2D dataset? (E.g. `ListLinePlot[{{1, 2}, {3, 1}}]`, `ListLinePlot[{{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {3, 1}}]`, `ListLinePlot[{{1, 2, 4}, {3, 1, 4}}]`) But I don't see how that would be related.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I haven't reported it. I agree that `data1` is unambiguous, so it should be counted as a bug.

Comment: Definitely a bug. Reporting it.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it a bit wrong. In your case the `ListLinePlot` is getting `{{{1,1},{8000,1}},{{1,0},{8000,0}}}` and `{{{1,1},{10,1},{8000,1}},{{1,0},{8000,0}}}` for plotting (use `Echo` for debugging, it's useful!), which doesn't make sense.
One of the main problems you have in your code, is that any function (if it takes more than 1 argument), should get a sequence of arguments and not a list.

It's as simple as:

```
Row[ListLinePlot[Tooltip[Sequence @@ #]] & /@ Transpose[{{data1, data2}, labels}], BaseStyle -> ImageSizeMultipliers -> 1]
```

**UPDATE**

The `Tooltip` seems not to be responsive when you try to map it over data values when plotting. Here is an alternative solution, while I didn't figure out how to do exactly what you want:

```
Row[ListLinePlot[#, PlotLabels -> labels] & /@ {data1, data2}, BaseStyle -> ImageSizeMultipliers -> 1]
```

**UPDATE**

Ok, I think I have the solution you want:

```
ListLinePlot[{Tooltip[#[[1]], labels[[1]]], Tooltip[Prepend[#[[2]], {0, 0}], labels[[2]]]}] & /@ {data1, data2}
```

or

```
hackIt[data_] := ReplacePart[data, 2 -> Prepend[data[[2]], data[[2, 1]]]]

attachLabels[data_, label_] :=
 MapThread[Tooltip[#1, #2] &, 
  {
   data, 
   label
   }
  ]

prepareData[data1_, data2_, labels_] :=
 MapThread[attachLabels[hackIt[#1], #2] &,
  {
   {data1, data2},
   Table[labels, 2]
   }
  ]

ListLinePlot /@ prepareData[data1, data2, labels]
```

What happens here, is I duplicate the first point of the second line in each of data you have. Why is this required, I don't know (seems a bug to me).

Comment: You wrap all the datasets by `Tooltip` at the top level, not the individual datasets. I need the upper line to have tooltip `"L1"` and the bottom line `"L2"`. With your approach both lines have the same label.