# ListPlot does not plot Labeled data under some conditions

Tags: plotting, bugs

**Bug fixed in 13.2.0 or earlier**

---

I don't understand the following behaviour I'm seeing with `ListPlot` and `Labeled`. It seems like a bug to me, but I'm wondering if someone else can explain it.

The following code produces an "empty" graph:

```
ListPlot[{{Labeled[{1, 0}, 1], Labeled[{-1, 0}, 1]}, 
          {Labeled[{0, -1}, 1], Labeled[{0, 1}, 1]}}]
```

[image: empty plot]

I say "empty" as it's not *quite* empty: it shows two of the labels, but none of the points. The axes are also correctly scaled to fit the data, but the data points are not visible.

If one adds a duplicate point, then the four data points are visible as I would have originally expected:

```
ListPlot[{{Labeled[{1, 0}, 1], Labeled[{-1, 0}, 1], Labeled[{-1, 0}, 1]}, 
          {Labeled[{0, -1}, 1], Labeled[{0, 1}, 1]}}],
```

Alternatively, if one of the points is removed from one of the lists, then the result is as expected as well:

```
ListPlot[{{Labeled[{1, 0}, 1]},
          {Labeled[{0, -1}, 1], Labeled[{0, 1}, 1]}}],
```

Moreover, if the lists of data contain only a single point each, then it works as I expect too:

```
ListPlot[{{Labeled[{1, 0}, 1]}, { Labeled[{0, 1}, 1]}}],
```

I can only seem to get the invalid result when I have two data points per list. Note that I want the data as two separate lists so that I can apply different directives to them to style the two lists of points separately.

Can anyone explain to me why the original example doesn't display four data points?

---

It's worth adding that, if the `Labeled` wrappers are removed, then the four points are also plotted as expected, though obviously without the required labels.

Comment: This is a bug, it worked in version 10.3

Comment: I avoided the `bug' tag originally as the tag description said not to apply it. I agree it's the appropriate tag though, thanks.

Comment: @JasonB. did you just check that? I don't have access to an older version to check myself, so can you confirm it as working in 10.3?

Comment: Another workaround is to add an invalid point (like `Indeterminate`) to one of the datasets, e.g., `ListPlot[{{Labeled[{1, 0}, 1], Labeled[{-1, 0}, 1], 
   Indeterminate}, {Labeled[{0, -1}, 1], Labeled[{0, 1}, 1]}}]`

Comment: same issue with other wrappers,.e.g. `Callout` and `Style`

Comment: For what it's worth, it doesn't seem to work on Version 11.3 or 10.0, but does work on 11.1 ?!?

Comment: Another workaround which seems to work:`ListPlot[{{whateversymbol}, {Labeled[{1, 0}, 1], 
   Labeled[{-1, 0}, 1]}, {Labeled[{0, -1}, 1], Labeled[{0, 1}, 1]}}]`

Answer (score 2):

It works as expected in `13.2.0`

[image: screen]